# List (UL/LI) displayed as grid - responsive (with Bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, list, grid, responsive

Is there any way that I can create a gallery like this

[image]

on bootstrap using an unordered list? I've accomplished that look with the column system but I really needed to use li items for this project.

So basically I want to create a list displayed as a grid. And it needs to be responsive as well. I want it turn into a one-column on mobile:

[image]

The reason why I want to use ul/li is because I'll be using wordpress and would like to use the wp_list_pages function.

This might be very easy but I just can't think of a solution that doesn't involve workarounds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is easier if use CSS Grids:

```css
 .gallary{
  margin-top:50px;
 width:80%;
  height:100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.5fr 1fr;
 grid-template-rows: 300px 200px;
 
 
}
.area1{
 grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2 ;
 background-color: blue;

}
.area2{
 grid-column:  2/4;
  grid-row:  1/1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.area3{
 grid-column:  1/2;
  grid-row:  2/2;
  background-color: green;
}
.area4{
 grid-column:  2/3;
  grid-row:  2/2;
  background-color: orange;
}
.area5{
 grid-column:  3/4;
  grid-row:  2/2;
  background-color: purple;
}
 @media (max-width: 650px) {
 
   .gallary{
  margin-top:50px;
 width:100%;
  height:100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 100%;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 
 
}
  .area1{
 grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 1/2 ;
 background-color: blue;

}
.area2{
 grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 2/3 ;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.area3{
 grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 3/4 ;
  background-color: green;
}
.area4{
 grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 4/5 ;
  background-color: orange;
}
.area5{
  grid-column: 1/-1;
  grid-row: 5/6;
  background-color: purple;
}
 }
```

```html
 <div class="gallary">
 
 <div class="area1">AAA</div>
   <div class="area2">AAA</div>
   <div class="area3">AAA</div>
   <div class="area4">AAA</div>
   <div class="area5">AAA</div>
  
 </div>
```

Comment: yeah, but i'm gonna use wordpress and i really want to use the wp_list_pages function on this